# How to query the Input field of a Paper Input element in dart

Tags: html, dart, dart-polymer, shadow-dom

So, I'm trying to access the input field hidden deep within  a paper input field. This is so that I can change the input type and so on. After inspecting the element, You can see that it has 2 shadow roots [as explained in this blog](http://terrageek.blogspot.com/2014/06/polymer-dart-paperelements-making-act.html). However, the method explained in that blog no longer works. I'm using dart version 1.5.3, polymer 0.12.0-dev.

I try to query the paper input like so:

```
querySelector('#paper-input-id').shadowRoot.querySelector('#input');
```

However, that returns null. This is because the shadowRoot property only returns the first shadow root. The input field is buried in the second shadow root. I guess what I am asking is if there is a generic way to select the nth-shadow root of an element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems exactly how I did it in the unit test for `<core-input>`

```dart
var input = dom.document.querySelector("#changeAndInputEvent") as CoreInput;
var domInput = (input.shadowRoot.olderShadowRoot.querySelector('#input') as dom.InputElement);
```

what also should work is

```dart
var domInput = (dom.document.querySelector("#changeAndInputEvent /deep/ #input");
```

or

```dart
var domInput = (dom.document.querySelector("* /deep/ #changeAndInputEvent /deep/ #input");
```

when the paper-input itself is inside a shadow-dom

Comment: This works with a pure core input. Core input has only 1 shadow root. Paper input is a child class of Core input and adds it's own shadow root with additional functionality. The Paper input's shadow root is inserted before the core input's shadow root. As such, the input element is hidden within the second shadow root. When you call the shadowRoot property on the paper input you only get access to it's own shadow root and not it's parent's shadow root. that is my problem. I want to query the parent classes shadowroot.

Comment: Sorry, seems I didn't read your question properly. I updated my answer.

Comment: I added another option I discovered recently.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `shadowRoot` and `olderShadowRoot`, which may change if for whatever reason `paper-input` decides to inherit something new that then inherits from `core-input`, try using the more generic `shadowRoots` map (note the 's'):

```
querySelector('#paper-input-id').shadowRoots['core-input'].querySelector('#input');
```

Comment: I haven't found that attribute in Polymer.dart. Have you used it in Dart or only in JS?

Comment: Now that I look deeper, I can't even get it to work in JS. It seems to only work in the Chrome Dev Tools console. And it's not in the spec.

Comment: Aha! I found where the shadowRoots property is [created in Polymer](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-dev/blob/8f8ecc197191e24d48b9285b4dde19aab3f38148/src/instance/base.js#L140)!

Comment: And it makes sense that this is unnecessary in native web components, because you're doing your own template cloning and Shadow DOM-ing, so you can just save a references to whatever you need in your createdCallback!

Comment: I don't know if this is in Polymer.dart, but it really should be. The accepted solution works fine from outside because you know you're working with a paper-input. However, if that code is in an extending element, then somebody extends *that* element, now there are 3 shadow roots, and the `olderShadowRoot` trick won't get you to the desired shadow root anymore.